# How do you make an element undragable in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, raphael

I made an element dragable using `element.drag(start, move, up);`

When I want to make the element undragable, I can somewhat achieve this using the method from **[the documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#events)**:

```
element.undrag(f); // Any undefined variable works as the argument
```

This makes it so that the element cannot be moved anymore.

This method has 2 problems:

1. This makes **all** elements on the page undragable.
2. `start()` still fires once for each element. I have an opacity change triggered in `start()` so it's quite obvious.

How do I make an element undragable so that only that element is affected and `start()` is not fired?

Here's what I have so far. The following tries to make the element undragable after one drag:

```
wiwindow.onload = function() {
    var R = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500),
    c = R.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({
        fill: "hsb(.8, 1, 1)",
        stroke: "none",
        opacity: .5
    }),
    d = R.circle(200, 200, 50).attr({
        fill: "hsb(1, 1, .8)",
        stroke: "none",
        opacity: .5
    }),        
    start = function () {
        // storing original coordinates
        this.ox = this.attr("cx");
        this.oy = this.attr("cy");
        this.attr({opacity: 1});
    },
    move = function (dx, dy) {
        // move will be called with dx and dy
        this.attr({cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});
    },
    up = function () {
        // restoring state
        this.attr({opacity: .5});
        this.undrag(notDefinedVariable); // Try to make it undragable
    };

    c.drag(move, start, up);    
    d.drag(move, start, up);     
};​
```

### **[Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WQtxU/)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902610/how-do-you-make-an-element-undragable-in-raphael/3905018#3905018

Has this issue been fixed or not?

Comment: @user880479 I'm using the same fiddle as above with 2.0 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AHungerArtist - Got it to work in 2.0 - I had some sort of funky "notDefinedVariable" ==> http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/VBVWa/ - It had to be included in previous version for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known bug. Will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dmitry. You have any idea when the next version will come out? Great library by the way; it's great fun to play with.

Comment: It should happen before Sencha Conference in November, but I am not giving any promises. It is going to be big 1.6 release.

Comment: @DmitryBaranovskiy For the record, using the same fiddle as linked above, it still shows this bug for Raphael 2.0. I'm using the latest version of Raphael and am also seeing this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Got it to work in [2.0](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/VBVWa/)

I had to change

```
this.undrag(notDefinedVariable); // Try to make it undragable
```

to

```
this.undrag(); // Try to make it undragable
```

Undefined had to be included in previous version to make it 1/2 work as described above.