# Mouseover function won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, raphael, mouseover

I am using Raphael graphics and animations which is a javascript library.  I want the user to mouseover the blue square in the bottom row, middle column.  When they mouseover I want the blue box to glow(Raphael function) black.  I am trying to use this function on rec8, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.  Can someone please correct my code or help me.  Thanks.  :)  Live Long and Prosper.

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<style type="text/css"> 
#input
{
margin-top:-200px;

}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="draw-here-raphael" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background: #666; z-index:0;">
</div>

<div id="input" style="z-index:99;" >
  <input type="text" value="0"; style="text-align:right;" /><br />
</form> 
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//all your javascript goes here
$(function() {
var r = new Raphael("draw-here-raphael"),

    // Store where the box is
    position = 'left',

    // Make our pink rectangle
    rec = r.rect(20, 20, 250, 300, 10).attr({"fill": "#fbb"});

    $("rect").mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).attr({"fill": "red"});
        });
    $("rect").mouseout(function(e) {
        $(this).attr({"fill": "#fbb"});
    }); 
    //first column
    rec2 = r.rect(30, 80, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
    rec3 = r.rect(30, 130, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
    rec4 = r.rect(30, 180, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
    rec5 = r.rect(30, 240, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
    //second column
    rec6 = r.rect(90, 80, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
    rec2 = r.rect(90, 130, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
    rec7 = r.rect(90, 180, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
    rec8 = r.rect(90, 240, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
        $("rec8").mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).glow({width:10});
        });
    $("rec8").mouseout(function(e) {
        $(this).glow({width:0});
    }); 
    //third column
    rec9 = r.rect(150, 80, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
    rec10 = r.rect(150, 130, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
    rec11 = r.rect(150, 180, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
    rec12 = r.rect(150, 240, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried moueseenter/mouseleave instead of mouseover/mouseout? That works in most cases far better.

Comment: @SvenBieder Raphael has it's own mouseout / mouseover.  Raphael doesn't have a moueseenter/mouseleave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selector:

```
$("rec8")
```

Is a jQuery selector for any `<rec8 />` tags. Those probably don't exist. You should attach your mouse events to the returned raphael elements:

```
rec8 = r.rect(90, 240, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
rec8.mouseover(function(e) {
    this.glow({width:10});
    });
rec8.mouseout(function(e) {
    this.glow({width:0});
});
```

> but for some reason when I mouseout it doesn't go away

That's because `glow` returns a new set that represents the glow, so you need to remove it. From the [Raphael documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.glow):

> Note: Glow is not connected to the element. If you change element attributes it won’t adjust itself.

You need to track the returned `set` that Raphael gives you as part of the glow, and remove it. Perhaps like this:

```
var rec8 = r.rect(90, 240, 50, 40, 5).attr({"fill": "blue"});
var rect8glow;
rec8.mouseover(function(e) {
    rect8glow = this.glow({width:10});
    });
rec8.mouseout(function(e) {
    rect8glow.remove();
});
```

You can see a working demo of that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vcsjones/WYHmp/).

Comment: Impressive.  That almost worked, but for some reason when I mouseout it doesn't go away.  And when I keep going back in that square the glow keeps getting darker.  Do you know how to fix this??

Comment: Never mind.  I figured it out.  I used the remove method.  Please +1 my question and I will approve your answer as soon as I can. :)

Comment: There's also a solution here. [How to add and remove glow for Raphael element?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8434080/1331430)

Comment: @StackOverflow Glad you figured it out. I updated my answer to include a solution for that.

Comment: Very cool that jsfiddle is pretty neat.  I will have to play around with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle for a live solution : http://jsfiddle.net/zhj2r/3/
As vcsjones stated, you were combining jquery and raphael, but they are not related.
By `$(this)` you wrap the raphael object in a jquery function call, which is wrong, and `$('rec4')` is not a valid jquery selector.
Moreover, the `glow` function returns a set of svg paths that show a conture of the targeted object, so by calling `glow({width : 0})`, you are not modifying the actual glow's width, but generatingg another glow element with the width 0.
Here are the things that I modified in order for your code to work :

```
rec.mouseover(function(e) {
    this.attr({"fill": "red"});
});
rec.mouseout(function(e) {
    this.attr({"fill": "#fbb"});
}); 
// ...
rec8.mouseover(function(e) {
    // keep a reference to the glow object so you can remove it later
    this.theGlow = this.glow({width:10});
});
rec8.mouseout(function(e) {
    this.theGlow.remove();
});
```